# How to disable zoom (ctrl + scroll wheel) in chrome dev tools?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, google-chrome-devtools

I want to disable zooming in and out `chrome dev tools` when I hold `ctrl` and scroll. One way is to completely disable this action from mouse settings for all applications but that I don't want.

Can I disable this scroll zooming behavior just for chrome dev tools?
I'm using Windows 10 and don't mind trying any `autohotkey` script.

Comment: Try the [#IfWinActive](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm) directive.

Comment: but I think that'll disable the shortcut for entire chrome browser. I want to disable it just for chrome-dev-tools

Answer (score 1):

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following script will work only if Dev Tools is undocked
from the Chrome main window, as otherwise it's hard to distinguish
which window is concerned. It will convert Ctrl+Scroll to Scroll
when Dev Tools is the active window:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2                    ; window title can contain text anywhere inside             
#IfWinActive, DevTools                  ; if the title contains "DevTools"
^WheelDown::Send, {WheelDown}           ; ctrl-wheel-down becomes wheel-down
^WheelUp::Send, {WheelUp}               ; ctrl-wheel-up becomes wheel-up
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: Thanks I just tried it but as you mentioned *work only if Dev Tools is undocked* :( that's a bummer. I always use dev-tools as docked.

Comment: When docked it doesn't have a separate window title.